# Is it possible to derive induction by extending CoC with recursion?

Tags: type-theory, lambda-calculus, functional-programming, automated-theorem-proving

Suppose we extended the CoC with primitive recursion; that is, we added a term `µ x . t` such that equality allowed unrolling recursive terms:

```
Γ |- µ x . a : *    Γ |- b : *    Γ |- a [a/x] == b
---------------------------------------------------
Γ |- a == b
```

And such that applying a recursive term to an argument unrolled it:

```
((µ x . a : T) q) ~> (a[a/x] q)
```

It seems that even that way, deriving induction wouldn't be possible. I've attempted the following (using Morteish syntax):

```
NAT =
  ∀ (P : *) ->
  ∀ (Zero : P) ->
  ∀ (Succ : NAT -> P) ->
  P

Zero =
  λ (P : *) ->
  λ (Zero : P) ->
  λ (Succ : NAT -> P) ->
  Zero

Succ =
  λ (n : NAT) ->
  λ (P : *) ->
  λ (Zero : P) ->
  λ (Succ : NAT -> P) ->
  Succ n

induction =
  λ (P : NAT -> *) ->
  λ (Z : P Zero) ->
  λ (S : ∀ (n : NAT) -> P n -> P (Succ n)) ->
  λ (n : NAT) ->
  n (P n) Z (λ (pred : NAT) -> S n (induction P Z S pred))
```

The problem here is that, when pattern-matching `n` on the definition of `induction`, we need to specify a return type. By specifying it to be `P n`, we get an error because, on the first case,

```
Z : P Zero
```

But should be:

```
Z : P n
```

And, on the second case,

```
(λ (p : NAT) -> S p (induction P Z S p)) : ∀ (p : NAT) -> P (Succ p)
```

But should be:

```
(λ (p : NAT) -> S p (induction P Z S p)) : ∀ (x : NAT) -> P n
```

The source of the problem seems to be that the system doesn't recognize that the following holds:

```
case n of
  Zero   -> ... here, n == Zero   ...
  Succ p -> ... here, n == Succ p ...
```

Or, in other words, after pattern matching a variable `n : NAT` as `Zero`, the system doesn't understand that `n` equals `Zero`. Similarly, it doesn't understand that `Succ (pred n) == n`. Is there any inherent reason for that, and is there any further extension that would allow this to check?

Comment: [Related discussion](https://i.imgur.com/HjMeklb.png) on #coq at Freenode.

Comment: The trouble you’re facing is with implementing dependent pattern matching; Aaron Stump’s recent papers discuss this and related problems; in particular this is discussed in “Self Types for Dependently Typed Lambda Encodings”, Sec. 2.1.

Comment: It would help if you said that you're adding *recursive types*, not just any kind of recursion. Or did I misunderstand you?

Comment: If you allow unrestricted recursive types, I would imagine you can cook up some sort of a "paradox" that allows you to inhabit every type.

Comment: Note what you added is not a correct version of the fixpoint operator $\mu$: instead of $ a [a/x] $ you’d need $a [\mu x.a/x]$! Also, it’s only at the level of proper types (because you use it at type `*`). But then, it seems not to be “primitive recursion”, because there’s no termination checking.
The more I look at it, the more it looks like an incorrect version of Stump’s paper I just cited; you’re learning why careless variants of what Stump does don’t work, unlike what he does. Maybe that’s a step to understanding his work?

Comment: Well in fact I got to this situation by trying to understand the CDLE paper (a follow up to the Self-types paper), and what justifies the things he did. I still don't get why all his primitives would be necessary for that, though, nor how a type being able to refer to its typed value helps here, but I'm making progress, I guess. I'll think more about that tomorrow when I'm less tired.

Comment: As per TAPL, `fix = λf:T→T. (λx:(µA.A→T). f (x x)) (λx:(µA.A→T). f (x x))` is well-typed, so as @Andrej Bauer pointed out, this has far-reaching consequences.